# Nagios Selinux contexts on RHEL7 equivelant

Tags: nagios, selinux

I installed nagios core and plugins for the first time, and can't get it to work with SElinux. The error in the audit log is,

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1441480084.865:710): avc:  denied  { execute } for 
pid=5444 comm="httpd" name="statusjson.cgi" dev="dm-1" ino=135240040 
scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 
tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file
```

System: `Scientific Linux 7`
Nagios: `4.1.1`

I was following the instructions [here](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/quickstart-fedora.html)

**It works when SElinux is in permissive mode (`setenforce 0`)**

(For anyone trying to figure out how to get the error log, SELinux policy seem to have, by default, not audit the httpd exec messages. I rebuilt the SELinux policy to enable all audit messages according to [this article](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Where_to_find_SELinux_permission_denial_details)

```
#semodule --disable_dontaudit --build
```

and looked at the log using

```
#sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log > auditlog.log
```

**Also, following the suggestions by sealert did not work for me**)

Comment: This should be reported as a bug to Red Hat.

Comment: Thx. I don't know much, but can I file a bug under RHEL7 eventhough I am using SL7?

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1260306 :)

Answer (score 1):

So changing the security context on the CGI scripts to `httpd_sys_script_exec_t` seem to have worked. Eventhough I am not sure if this is the desired solution.

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t /usr/local/nagios/sbin
```

More info: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/apache

Note that `chcon` changes context only temporarily; if the filesystem is relabeled or `restorecon` is run, the context will revert to the default type. To [change the context permanently](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext), run:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t /usr/local/nagios/sbin
restorecon -v /usr/local/nagios/sbin
```